# Mongoose: how to define a combination of field values to be unique?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

If I have a schema like this:

```
    module.exports = (driver) ->
      InvitationSchema = new driver.schema(
        id: driver.id
        createdAt:
          type: Date
          'default': Date.now
        senderId: driver.id
        receiverId: driver.id
        accepted:
          type: Boolean
          'default': false
        rejected:
          type: Boolean
          'default': false)

      InvitationSchema.index { senderId: 1, receiverId: 1}, { unique: true }    
      InvitationSchema.index { receiverId: 1, senderId: 1}, { unique: true }

      return driver.db.model('invitation', InvitationSchema);
```

How is it possible to ensure no documents are created:

1) With the same sender and receiver value.

2) The reverse of these values, ie. an existing entity with senderId value equal to a new receiverId and the new senderId equal to the same existing entity's receiverId.

Comment: have you tried to add the unique flag? check the [mongoose schema types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: I have tried adding `Schema.index { senderId: 1, receiverId: 1}, { unique: true }` and an index of 
 `Schema.index { receiverId: 1, senderId: 1}, { unique: true }` at the same time.

Comment: you used Schmea.index { senderId: 1, receiverId: 1}, { unique: true } or invitation.index?

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify what I tried. I also tried these two indices individually, though the expected behavior remains inadequate.